# update url dynamically inside a model view controller framework

Tags: php, url, model-view-controller

I made an MVC framework myself. I am stuck at a point of url update. This is what happens when i try to log in for example:

1. When i press the login button, the URL looks like this: localhost/Login_controller/
2. The login controller gets called and loads the required model that authenticate the credentials.
3. Model returns the status to the controller and controller loads the respective view. In my case its profile.php.
4. The url should look like this now: localhost/profile/

> > $this->load->view(profile);

After executing the above line of code, the url stays the same **localhost/Login_Controller/**

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

I got the help to design MVC from this tutorial. [MVC Tutorial that i studied](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)

**applications/router.php**

```
class router{
   private $registry;
   public function __construct($registry){
         $this->registry = $registry; 
   }   
   public function getController(){
       $url = $_GET['url'];
       if($contoller_path){
           include $controller_path;   // if controller exits the path will be included
           $url = new $url.Controller(); // instantiating the object for controller
           $url->auth_login();
        }
    }
 }
```

**controllers/Login_controller.php**

```
class Login_controller extends controller{

      public function __construct($registry){
         parent::_construct( $registry); 
      }   
      public function auth_login(){
       $url = $_GET['url'];
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];
       if($model_path){
           include $_path;
           $this->registry->url = new $url.model();
           $status = $this->registry->{url->auth_login}($username, $password);

           if($status == 'success'){

            //HERE....
// I want to change the url localhost/login_controller to localhost/profile/

               $this->registry->template->show('profile');  
           }if($status == 'failure'){
               $this->registry->template->show('index');
           }  
        }
    }
 }
```

**model/aut_login_hmodel**

```
 class auth_login_model extends model{

  public function __construct($registry){
         parent::_construct( $registry); 
      } 
   public function auth_login($username, $password){
       //here is the code to query db and all..

       if($success){
           return $success;
       }else{
          return $failure; 
       }
    }
 }
```

**application/template.php**

```
class template{
   private $registry;
   public function __construct($registry){
         $this->registry = $registry; 
   }   
   public function show($view){

       if(is_readable($view_path)){
           include $view_path;  // if view exists, it would load

       }else{
           include $index_path; // if view does not exists, index page loads
       } 
    }
 }
```

Hope this is enough to elaborate.

Comment: What should the URL look like after executing that code? Also, we might need to see the definition of the `view` method to understand what you mean.

Comment: @halfer i have added the link. I have designed the framework same way after reading this tutorial.

Comment: I have edited the post and gave the full details to make you understand.